# Catch and identify source of browser launch events

Tags: windows-xp, browser

My Windows XP computer is exhibiting strange behaviour, launching multiple browser windows, but not to any URL. Initially this was in Firefox, but when I uninstalled it the same happened in IE. Norton 360 detects no malware, and I wonder if there is some application that is accidentally causing the problem.

I'd like to diagnose the problem further. It seems that the default browser is being launched by something, so I'd like to work out the culprit. Is there some method (or handy utility) that can catch requests to XP to launch the default browser, and identify the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and set it to only show process events. You'll see which processes are lauching the browser.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have malware trying to launch programs

norton or your firewall may be blocking the sites so you are seeing empty site launches

try launching the microsoft malware removal tool

http://www.microsoft.com/security/malwareremove/default.mspx